# How to scope events using $.on() when passing in an object

Tags: jquery, binding, jquery-on

The jQuery docs show the following:

```
$( "div.test" ).on({
  click: function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
  }, mouseenter: function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "inside" );
  }, mouseleave: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "inside" );
  }
});
```

We can pass in an object to the `.on()` function so that it will determine what it will do based on the object.

But what if I want the equivalent of

```
$('div.test').on('click', 'a.button', function(){foo();}
```

IE i want to monitor  `div.test` for `click`, `mousenter` and `mouseleave` events on an `a.button` element using the object style outlined at the top here

Answer (score 1):

According to [jQuery's source of fn.on](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.on)

```
if (typeof types === "object") {
    // ( types-Object, selector, data )
    if (typeof selector !== "string") {
        // ( types-Object, data )
        data = data || selector;
        selector = undefined;
    }
    for (type in types) {
        this.on(type, selector, data, types[type], one);
    }
    return this;
}
```

If an object is passed in it will check if `selector` is a sting. If it is then it will leave it alone. Next it will iterate over that object just doing each `on` again.

So your code would be:

```
$( "div.test" ).on({
  click: function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
  }, mouseenter: function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "inside" );
  }, mouseleave: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "inside" );
  }
}, 'a.button');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3MWQA/)